# Recommeneded light weight Bitcoin library for an Android app

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoinj

I am looking for a light weight Bitcoin library for an Android app.

I basically need a Bitcoin library that lets me create a private/public key pair (or preferably a wallet with keys that can be serialized). To be able to set the most appropriate fee for a transaction and submit it to the Bitcoin network from a Android app.

I noticed BitcoinJ and recently a new addition called BitherJ (https://github.com/bither/bitherj) which looks promising.

I am wondering which is best to use. Anyone has experience with this and can give pros/cons on each?

Answer (score 3):

I would reccommend using bitcoinj. https://bitcoinj.github.io/. Its widely used and highly supported.

Some Android apps that use bitcoinj:

[Bitcoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet)

[Hive Android Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hivewallet.androidclient.wallet)